# Is there a way to process values ​passed from React in django and then send them back to React?

Tags: reactjs, django

I'm cooperating with my friend to make toy project using Django RESTful api and React. I'm doing with django.

This is my simplified model.py:

```
class Map(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    monsters = models.ManyToManyField('Monster', blank=True, related_name='maps')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Quest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    goal = models.TextField()
    recommended_map = models.ManyToManyField(Map, related_name='quests')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I completed to pass quest list to react side using api. Users can select several quests from that list.

What I want to do is finding a recommened_map that the user selected quest has in common and sending it back to React.

I've searched all day but I couldn't. Is it impossible?

Comment: you can make an Ajax call once you have a `quest list`. then on selection, you can call an API, and based on the selection you can return `recommended_map` as a response to react and use it any way you want.

Comment: @HemalPatel Thanks for giving me a keyword. I'll try it right away